# How to make sure slice is using a copy of another slice and not a reference to it?

Tags: go, slice

I'm learning GO and I have a theoretical problem.

How do I use a copy of slice rather than a reference to it?

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    // slice containing 3 items
    slice1 := []int{1, 2, 3}
    // make an empty slice
    slice2 := make([]int, 2, 5)
    // create slice3 by appending int 4 to slice2
    slice3 := append(slice2, 4)
    // print [0 0 4]
    fmt.Println(slice3)
    // copy elements of slice1 onto slice2
    copy(slice2, slice1)
    // print [1 2 3] [1 2] [1 2 4]; how to make sure slice3 is using a copy [0 0 4]?
    fmt.Println(slice1, slice2, slice3)
}
```

[problem playground link](https://play.golang.org/p/oIrmq5vpdK)

I have came up with a potential solution, but it is pointless as it relies on slice3 being created empty and slice2 being copied via `copy()` onto slice3. Is there no shortcut?

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    // slice containing 3 items
    slice1 := []int{1, 2, 3}
    // make an empty slice
    slice2 := make([]int, 2, 5)
    // create slice3, copy slice2 and append int 4 to slice3
    slice3 := make([]int, 2)
    copy(slice3, slice2)
    slice3 = append(slice3, 4)
    // print [0 0 4]
    fmt.Println(slice3)
    // copy elements of slice1 onto slice2
    copy(slice2, slice1)
    // print [1 2 3] [1 2] [0 0 4];
    fmt.Println(slice1, slice2, slice3)
}
```

[solution playground link](https://play.golang.org/p/5zKokhchii)

**EDIT:**

I've [read](http://openmymind.net/Controlling-Array-Growth-In-Golang/) that there is a peculiar behaviour that in this naive example would work as a solution (see below). However, in any other case it would not work.
Basically, if the empty slice is created without the size of an underlying array being specified, GO's append function provides a copy of that array, otherwise, if there is room to grow, append will return a slice that references the original array.

Note: the only change is `slice2 := make([]int, 2, 5)` into `slice2 := make([]int, 2)`

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    // slice containing 3 items
    slice1 := []int{1, 2, 3}
    // make an empty slice
    slice2 := make([]int, 2)
    // create slice3 by appending int 4 to slice2
    slice3 := append(slice2, 4)
    // print [0 0 4]
    fmt.Println(slice3)
    // copy elements of slice1 onto slice2
    copy(slice2, slice1)
    // print [1 2 3] [1 2] [1 2 4]; how to make sure slice3 is using a copy [0 0 4]?
    fmt.Println(slice1, slice2, slice3)
}
```

[playground with a wanted behaviour](https://play.golang.org/p/UQ4_JsoG4O)

So the question becomes: Is it possible to replicate the behaviour of the above, when the slice we are appending to points to an array with specified size and room to grow?

**EDIT 2:**
I think there is some confusion as to what I want to achieve.
How to get the result of the second call while passing a slice in the format used in the first call?

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println("s3 references an array of s1")
    worker(make([]int, 2, 5))
    fmt.Println("\ns3 copies an array of s1")
    worker(make([]int, 2))
}

func worker(s1 []int) {
    s2 := []int{1, 2, 3}
    fmt.Println(s1)
    s3 := append(s1, 4)
    fmt.Println(s3)
    copy(s1, s2)
    fmt.Println(s3)
}
```

[playground](https://play.golang.org/p/KHpG52qln8)

Comment: If you add or change slice2 but slice3 doesn't change, you have a copy.

Comment: I think you've made this a lot more complicated than it needs to be. If you know how slices work, this all seems very straightforward: http://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals.

Comment: Oh, I think I finally get what you're asking. How do you know if `append` simply appended into a slice that had the capacity or returned a new slice when the original didn't have the space. For that, I'd simply say don't put yourself in a place where it'd matter.

Comment: I find this question confusing. Are you 1. trying to ensure that several slice variables (slice1, slice2) refer to the same, common, underlying storage, so updates through one, update the other, or are you 2. trying to ensure that slice2 who's values were copied from slice1, *never* refers to the same underlying storage as slice1, or something else?

Comment: @gbulmer Sorry about that, I wrote an answer which I hope clarifies that.

Comment: @CoreyOgburn  Yes, that's it. I found it inconsistent and thought that I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: @JimB Thank you for that post I've found it informative and it actually explained the issue, I still find the inconsistency weird, but I guess it is not 'seen' in real code.

Answer (score 0):

A few people commented that I was not clear enough last night. So I would like to clarify and provide an answer that I arrived at with the help of  @CoreyOgburn and @JimB

I was learning about slices in GO and I found an inconsistency, that led me to believe I'm doing something wrong. While hardly a real life example I found the following a good example of the copy and append functionality.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println("s3 references an array of s1")
// we pass a slice of length 2 and capacity 5
    worker(make([]int, 2, 5))
    fmt.Println("\ns3 copies an array of s1")
// we pass a slice of lenght 2 and capacity 2
    worker(make([]int, 2))
}

func worker(s1 []int) {
// create new slice for future use
    s2 := []int{1, 2, 3}
    fmt.Println(s1)
// create a new slice by appending a value to a slice passed into this function 
    s3 := append(s1, 4)
// s3 holds whatever was passed into this function + int 4, that we just appended
    fmt.Println(s3)
// copy contents of s2 onto s1
    copy(s1, s2)
// if s1 had spare capacity when it was passed i.e. make([]int, 2, 5) s3 will be referencing the same array as s1, hence s3 will now hold the same values as s1
// if s1 capacity was the same as its length i.e. make([]int, 2) s3 will be referencing a new array after append(), hence copy has no effect on the values of s3
    fmt.Println(s3)
}
```

@JimB posted a comment with a link to a [blog post explaining how slices work](http://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals), which is a great read if you are learning the language.
What is most important in the section `A possible "gotcha"` there is an explanation of a 'fix' to a real life scenario, that can be extrapolated as a fix the inconsistency in my example. (create a copy of a passed slice and use that instead)
[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/_97XT0mDdd)

Comment: Ah! So you were puzzled because it looks like their is inconsistent behaviour (two very different behaviours, almost bug-like), purely depending on the initial *capacity* of a slice. That is a good blog, I'd also recommend [Strings, bytes, runes and characters in Go](http://blog.golang.org/strings). It isn't quite as profound as the slices blog, however I was very curious about the relationship between byte slices and strings. Specifically, is a string just a read-only []byte. I'm glad I asked, and you answered, because I thought your question was asking something slightly different.